# Web Scraping: Issues With Set_values and crawlr

Tags: r, url, web-scraping, rvest

My Goal: Using R, scrape all light bulb model #s and prices from homedepot. 
My Problem: I can not find the URLs for ALL the light bulb pages. I can scrape one page, but I need to find a way to get the URLs so I can scrape them all.

Ideally I would like these pages 
https://www.homedepot.com/p/TOGGLED-48-in-T8-16-Watt-Cool-White-Linear-LED-Tube-Light-Bulb-A416-40210/205935901

but even getting the list pages like these would be ok
https://www.homedepot.com/b/Lighting-Light-Bulbs/N-5yc1vZbmbu

I tried crawlr -> Does not work on homedepot (maybe because https?)I tried to get specific pages 
I tried Rvest -> I tried using html_form and set_values to put light bulb in the search box, but the form comes back

```
[[1]]
<form> 'headerSearchForm' (GET )
  <input hidden> '': 21
  <input text> '': 
  <button > '<unnamed>
```

and set_value will not work because  is '' so the error comes back 
error: attempt to use zero-length variable name.

I also tried using the paste function and lapply

```
tmp <- lapply(0:696, function(page) {
  url <- paste0("https://www.homedepot.com/b/Lighting-Light-Bulbs/N- 
 5yc1vZbmbu?Nao=", page, "4&Ns=None")
  page <- read_html(url)
  html_table(html_nodes(page, "table"))[[1]]
})
```

I got the error : error in html_table(html_nodes(page,"table"))[[1]]: script out of bounds.

I am seriously at a loss and any advice or tips would be so fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it through rvest and tidyverse.

You can find a listing of all bulbs starting in this page, with a pagination of 24 bulbs per page across 30 pages:

https://www.homedepot.com/b/Lighting-Light-Bulbs-LED-Bulbs/N-5yc1vZbm79

Take a look at the pagination grid at the bottom of the initial page. I drew a(n ugly) yellow oval around it:

[image: Pagination grid with 30 pages/links]

You could extract the link to each page listing 24 bulbs by following/extracting the links in that pagination grid.

Yet, just by comparing the urls it becomes evident that all pages follow a pattern, with "https://www.homedepot.com/b/Lighting-Light-Bulbs-LED-Bulbs/N-5yc1vZbm79" as root, and a tail where the
last digit characters represent the first lightbulb displayed, "?Nao=***24***"

So you could simply infer the structure of each url pointing to a display of the bulbs. The following command creates such a list in R:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

index_list <- as.list(seq(0,(24*30), 24)) %>% paste0("https://www.homedepot.com/b/Lighting-Light-Bulbs-LED-Bulbs/N-5yc1vZbm79?Nao=", . )
```

Now, to extract the url for each lightbulb page, a combuination of a function and purrt's  map function would come handy.

To exctract the individual bulbs url from the index pages, we can call this:

```
scrap_bulbs <- function(url){
   object <- read_html(as.character(url))
   object <- html_nodes(x = object, xpath = "//a[@data-pod-type='pr']")
   object <- html_attr(x = object, 'href')
   Sys.sleep(10) ## Courtesy pause of 10 seconds, prevents the website from possibly blocking your IP
   paste0('https://www.homedepot.com', object)
}
```

Now we store the results in a list create by map().

```
bulbs_list <- map(.x = index_list, .f =  scrap_bulbs)
unlist(bulbs_list)
```

Done!

Comment: Thank you!! Once I ran this I got a list but it doesn't include any URLs, only [[1]]-[[31]] and they type all says NULL. Is there a way to see the list? and how would I refer to it when using them urls for nodes etc?

Comment: Hello MtnBee. Please retry the edited code. I had made a mistake on the scrap_bulbs() function.

Comment: Glad it helped! Do not forget to vote for the answer if it worked :)